# Can Windows Updates affect stability of the IIS?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis, windows-update

We're having stability problems in our site - it becomes unresponsive to periods of a few minutes or about 20 minutes.
While investigating the issue, I noticed that the server is not being maintained - for example, no Windows updates were ever installed (in about a year an a half).
Our administrators claim that there were no relevant stability related updated released anyway, so the updates aren't important.

Technical background: We have an Asp.Net MVC 4 site on IIS 7.5, running on Windows Server 2008 R2.

Can Windows Updates affect stability?

Comment: This is unrelated to this question, but just in case it rings a bell: The IIS/Thread Pool becomes unresponsive with nothing visible in the event viewer. The IIS logs also have nothing except for an empty gap with no entries when the site is down, and the IIS Header when the site returns (version number, column names, etc).

Comment: I humbly apologize if the question is off topic - I know it is border-line. I looked at the chat first but the description said they were not accepting questions.

Answer (score 1):

> Our administrators claim that there were no relevant stability related updated released 
>   anyway, so the updates aren't important.

And that is a good reason not to install the general stability updates and more important seucrity updates for the servers?

As someone maintaining servers for customers I am ashamed that those people call themselves Administrators. IMHO firing time.

Comment: As for security: The general claim is that the server is the last link behind Intrusion Perversion systems and firewalls, but I kept it out of the scope of the question. To be honest, as a developer, I was quite shocked to discover there are no updates on our production server, but no one around me shares my concerns.

Comment: As an admin I do not care whether the server is buried in 10 meters concrete. Security is by layers and they ignore the last layer.

Comment: I assure you, you are preaching to the choir. But I am asked to provide other reasons to justify the updates, with "security" not being a relevant claim (it was the first thing I tried, of course).